# How many prime numbers are there whose squares' decimal representation consist solely of integer squares?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

I am on the hunt for prime squares which decimal digits build up squares.

The smallest I have found is:

$$7^2 = 49 \cases{4=2^2\\ 9=3^2}$$

Another one is $$191^2 = 36481 \cases{36=6^2\\4=2^2\\81=9^2}$$
and
$$223^2 = 49729 \cases{49=7^2\\729=27^2}$$

So we can conclude that there do exist at least a few.

Now to the question, how many of these can we find?

Can we prove there can only be finite?

Or can we estimate some distribution?

To make a more strict formulation:

Let us assume the prime square has $n$ decimal digits

1. neighboring digits can be grouped together in a **non-overlapping** way
2. each group consisting of at least $1$ digit and at most $n-1$ digits

Comment: "I am on the hunt for prime squares which decimal digits build up squares." Why?

Comment: $13^2=16\ 9$. $19^2=36\ 1$. $37^2=1\ 36\ 9$. $41^2=16\ 81$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Maybe I should have added recreational mathematics as a tag. It is just a curiosity. I don't know of any usefulness of it yet.

Comment: Is there any reason to restrict this to primes? Since the property doesn't seem to have anything to do with primes, to me it makes more sense to look at the general problem, which is likely easier.

Comment: @Ingix hmm that is a good question. I don't think I had any particular reason in mind for the number being prime. I just like thinking about primes and did not think about the possibility that it could hold equally well for integers in general. But there seem to be so many people who like the question so it would probably be a rather bad time to change it now.

Comment: If not restricted to primes there is the infinite sequence: $12^2=144, 1002^2=1004004, 100002^2=10000400004$, etc.

Comment: @nickgard yep you are correct. It would apparently be a bit too easy to find such sequences.

Comment: Assuming "trivial squares" $1=1^2$, $0=0^2$ count toward examples ($19^2=361=(36,1)$ and $97^2=9409=(9, 4, 0, 9)$ are examples), you are looking for terms of [A019547](https://oeis.org/A019547) whose square root is a prime number. Out of $\pi(10^6)=78498$ primes below one million, $457$ of them satisfy your property. ([Here is a list.](https://pastebin.com/Pv4ubm5f))